# ValueError: X has 31 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 32 features as input

Tags: python, jupyter

My code was working fine but suddenly I started getting this error. I've looked at the solutions but I need to see the solution with an example on the code so I can understand it. I do not know how to do it . Can you help me?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape

model training
def model_acc(model):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print(str(model)+ ' --> ' +str(acc))

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
model_acc(lr)

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lasso = Lasso()
model_acc(lasso)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model_acc(dt)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
model_acc(rf)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

parameters = {'n_estimators':[10, 50, 100],
              'criterion':['squared_error','absolute_error','poisson']}

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=parameters)

grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_model = grid_fit.best_estimator_

best_model.score(X_test, y_test)
X_test.columns

import pickle
with open('predictor.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(best_model, file)
pred_value = best_model.predict([[8, 1.3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
pred_value
```

I tried several answers on this site but I couldn't. Could you please share the solution with me through the code on this issue?

Comment: Please provide the error you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a missconception in ML. The algorithm you are working with has 32 columns, and to make an output prediction, you need to feed him another 32 columns and at least 1 row.

To fix this kind of problems you need to check your algorithm creation, the train,test you gave while creating it and the dataframe you are trying to predict right now. They need to have the same columns.

Try to print the columns of your train dataframe and the columns you are using right now, maybe you are training your dataset with the index, or maybe with the labels.